Issues with GL Errors in Flutter While Running on Android
I am developing a Flutter application and encountering several GL-related errors when running it on an Android emulator. Below are the details of the error messages I am receiving:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52031/8ctpC63T6n0=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...
I/WebViewFactory( 9118): Loading com.google.android.webview version 113.0.5672.136 (code 567263637)
W/ziparchive( 9118): Unable to open '/data/app/~~DXixBrx5e-2QhZxz6Gcj3Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-JqnhccsX8Tr4xewcGmPetg==/TrichromeLibrary.dm': No such file or directory
W/se.kwcalculator( 9118): Entry not found
D/nativeloader( 9118): Configuring clns-7 for other apk /data/app/~~DXixBrx5e-2QhZxz6Gcj3Q==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-JqnhccsX8Tr4xewcGmPetg==/TrichromeLibrary.apk. target_sdk_version=34
...
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 9118): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2206 GL error 0x502
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 9118): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2206 GL error 0x502
...
Flutter Version: I am using the latest stable version of Flutter.
Development Environment: I am running the app on an Android emulator with the architecture sdk gphone64 x86 64.
Actions Taken: I have tried cleaning the project (flutter clean) and rebuilding it (flutter pub get and flutter build), but the errors persist.
Observed Behavior: The app runs, but I receive many warning and error messages related to GL (OpenGL) and missing files.
Note: If I make a change and run the application, it displays and works correctly, but if I stop and relaunch it, I get a blank screen. This started happening after I updated Flutter.
these are the dependencies I am using:
environment:
sdk: '>=3.3.0 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
intl: ^0.19.0
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
google_mobile_ads: ^5.0.0
dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
Does anyone know what might be causing these errors and how I can fix them? Could it be related to the emulator setup or some issue in my Flutter configuration?
Thanks in advance for your help!

It sounds like an issue with Android Emulator. Check this thread on GitHub. In short, you can try to downgrade Android Emulator to 34.1.20. It worked for me. Be aware that location services are quite broken in 34.1.20.
Also, you can try to clear your app cache inside the emulator before running/debugging.
